# Winforms Ввод с клавиатуры в Panel

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть Panel, на нем навешан навешано событие PreviewKeyDown. При попытке ввода работает только ангилийский язык, даже если язык переключен на русский. Моя задача состоит в следующем - получить букву, добавить в переменную и отрисовать её в Panel. Вот как я делаю это в своем коде.

```
private void editor_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
    inputText += (char)e.KeyValue;
    editor.Invalidate();
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38787453/12888024

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/320914/12888024

Comment: Или еще можно событие `KeyPress` использовать, там в аргументах есть `e.KeyChar`

Comment: спасибо) помогло